# Why does django send_mail fails to send email with no errors?

Tags: django, smtp, gmail, sendmail, wagtail

I want to use send_mail in django, however it doesn't send any email. Here is my settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MY-GMAIL-USERNAME@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MY-GMAIL-PASSWORD'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
```

Then, I run `python manage.py shell`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

subject = 'Test Subject'
message = 'Test Message'
email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
recipient_list = ['MY-YAHOO-USERNAME@yahoo.com']
send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
```

It doesn't send the email and it prints:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Test Subject
From: MY-GMAIL-USERNAME@gmail.com
To: MY-YAHOO-USERNAME@yahoo.com
Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 21:02:16 -0000
Message-ID: <157592533640.18842.5494330274157836181@thinkpad-e560>

Test Message
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
```

which seems to have no errors. Why doesn't it send the email? What is wrong? Why doesn't it log any errors?

Following [this page](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/), I've tried a pure python way and it works fine:

```
import smtplib, ssl

smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 465
sender_email = "MY-GMAIL-USERNAME@gmail.com"
password = 'MY-GMAIL-PASSWORD'
receiver_email = 'MY-YAHOO-USERNAME@yahoo.com'
context = ssl.create_default_context()
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context)
server.login(sender_email, password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, 'Test Message')
```

As I mentioned, this pure python way works fine! I'm confused.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to pass `fail_silently=True`, see the docs for [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail).

Comment: Thanks! I tried with "fail_silently=False". Nothing changed. I will edit my question to include "fail_silently=False" @DanielRoseman

Comment: If calling `send_mail` is outputting to the console then you probably have your email backend set to `'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`. Are you certain you have the smtp backend in your settings?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You mean "fail_silently=False", right?

Comment: @IainShelvington is probably right. If you are seeing your email output in the console then you must have the  `console.EmailBackend` configured. Print the value of `settings.EMAIL_BACKEND` just before calling `send_mail`

Comment: @ivissani Yes you are right! when I print settings.EMAIL_BACKEND, It returns console.EmailBackend. But in my settings.py It is smtp.EmailBackend. That's Strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @IainShelvington and @ivissani, I've figured it out. I use wagtail cms on top of django and created the project using "wagtail start mysite". for more information see [this](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7/getting_started/index.html).

in wagtail standard project structure, there are base.py, dev.py and production.py instead of settings.py.

The Email settings was in base.py but in dev.py, EMAIL_BACKEND was overwritten. This is the dev.py when you create a django project using wagtail:

```
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'MY-SITE-KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: define the correct hosts in production!
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] 

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

So I fixed the problem by removing EMAIL_BACKEND from dev.py

Answer (score 0):

Start your python file with this:

```
import os
import sys
import django
django.setup()

# rest of your code
```

`from django.conf import settings` imports your settings but it doesn't set it as os environment.

`os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'` - this also should work